# asp.net login control with internet explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, login-control

I have an ASP.net login control in my web application. While I run the application in Internet Explorer and type the password it is displayed as question marks.

Is anyone able to solve this problem? It would be very useful for my project.

Comment: I need to displayed the password as dot symbol

Comment: This is a css issue. I remember coming across this in the past. I think it required changing the fonts to some standard fonts like  Arial, Verdana, Times New Roman, MS Sans Serif, etc.

Comment: If you are setting the fonts using Themes or directly. Please check if you are using standard fonts or else you'll have issue while running the app in different browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally this means that the font it's trying to use does not contain the character that was specified.  Did you set a specific character or a non-default font?  (The default symbol should be the asterisk, * - not sure about the font.)

Also, check the character set for your pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="pwd" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: ASP.NET login control does this for you automatically.

Comment: yes.. <asp:Login runat="server"></asp:Login> will do this automatically.. if this not coming for satya, then i assumed he is using normal textbox...

Answer (score 0):

Change the font to something other, then you will get  aquestion mark instaed. Don't remember the font name. Instaed you can also handle the key events to display a question mark when a key is typed.